# If using javascript to get information on click, put it in another field

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I just learned javascript and encountered a problem, do not know how to write!

I hope that after clicking one of the options, the information on the selected option, such as the food name and price, can be brought to the blue area to display!
But I don't know how to proceed, I hope everyone can help, thank you.

```js
let plan = document.querySelector('.paln');
let price = document.querySelector('.price');

let item = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
  item[i].addEventListener('click', showplan, false);
}

function showplan() {
  console.log('hello')
}
```

```css
.product＿list {
  display: flex;
}

.product＿list .item {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.product＿list .item h2 {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.product＿list .item:hover {
  border: 1px solid #222;
}

.product＿list .bold {
  border: 3px solid;
}

.show {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="product＿list">
  <li class="item">
    <h2>coke</h2>
    <p>$100</p>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <h2>fries</h2>
    <p>$600</p>
  </li>
</ul>

<h2 class="show">Your food of choice is<span class="plan"></span>price is<span class="price"></span></h2>
```

Comment: `paln` != `plan`

Comment: `function showplan(evt) { console.log(evt.currentTarget); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you needs get the object clicked, so if you click at any where of `<li>` your target goings to be the `h2` or `<p>` so you need search the closest `<li>` tag.

```js
let plan = document.querySelector('.plan');
let price = document.querySelector('.price');

let item = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
  item[i].addEventListener('click', showplan, false);
}

function showplan(e) {
  const planSelected = e.target.closest('li').querySelector('h2');
  const priceSelected = e.target.closest('li').querySelector('p');
  plan.innerHTML = planSelected.innerHTML;
  price.innerHTML = priceSelected.innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: Please explain what is happening in this code so that the asker would understand what this piece of code means. And not just type in "easy"

Comment: Thank you ~ but I follow your way, but there is an error problem

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerHTML') 」

Comment: ok, here is the example: https://jsfiddle.net/jon_eldiablo/7wgj50vt/2/

Comment: with styles: https://jsfiddle.net/jon_eldiablo/7wgj50vt/3

Answer (score 0):

If you click on either of the buttons it activates a function that changes the contents of `.show`

```js
document.getElementById("item1").addEventListener('click', () => {document.querySelector(".show").innerText = "Your food of choice is Coke Price is $100";})
document.getElementById("item2").addEventListener('click', () => {document.querySelector(".show").innerText = "Your food of choice is Fries Price is $600";})
```

```css
.product＿list {
  display: flex;
}

.product＿list .item {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.product＿list .item h2 {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.product＿list .item:hover {
  border: 1px solid #222;
}

.product＿list .bold {
  border: 3px solid;
}

.show {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="product＿list">
  <li class="item" id="item1">
    <h2>coke</h2>
    <p>$100</p>
  </li>
  <li class="item" id="item2">
    <h2>fries</h2>
    <p>$600</p>
  </li>
</ul>

<h2 class="show">Your food of choice is<span class="plan"></span> price is<span class="price"></span></h2>
```

Comment: Thank you~

The current way of writing is to write the information yourself. If I have a lot of menus today, is this a good way?
Can the user click on an item to capture the information of the item and put it in the blue frame?

Comment: This isn't the best to do for you have to write the information yourself.